# Company Wide Shared Folder

Tags: office365, onedrive

What's the most common way to create a (mostly) company-wide shared folder for a small business (< 20 employees) with Office 365 and OneDrive?

I've searched back and forth on Google and can't get a straight answer to this question.

Currently, everything is set up with a personal business OneDrive and it works well, but there are a series of forms and other documents that most staff needs access to. There is no single 'owner' for the documents and both view and edit capability is needed.

Some articles suggest creating a Sharepoint Team Site, others say to have an individual user share with other users.

I would like if these shared files could appear in Windows Explorer and within the Office apps. It seems like you can't sync a shared folder (add to OneDrive) with business accounts on more recent versions of Windows.

Has anyone seen a proper guide for how to do this? It seems like having both OneDrive and SharePoint is counter intuitive.

Thanks!